# Как в Python загрузить картинку в буфер обмена из url

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, url, clipboard

Как в Python загрузить картинку в буфер обмена из url. Скачать ее и загрузить в буфер обмена в Windows 10.

Пример картинки:
[Картинка из Википедии](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/20/Emergency_hospital_during_Influenza_epidemic%2C_Camp_Funston%2C_Kansas_-_NCP_1603.jpg/220px-Emergency_hospital_during_Influenza_epidemic%2C_Camp_Funston%2C_Kansas_-_NCP_1603.jpg)

Comment: тут рассказывают о работе с буфером обмена:
[клик](https://python-scripts.com/question/6677)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте следующим образом.

Установите библиотеку PyWin32 `pip install pywin32`.

Затем запускайте код:

```
import win32clipboard
from PIL import Image
import requests as r
from io import BytesIO

img = r.get('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/20/Emergency_hospital_during_Influenza_epidemic%2C_Camp_Funston%2C_Kansas_-_NCP_1603.jpg/220px-Emergency_hospital_during_Influenza_epidemic%2C_Camp_Funston%2C_Kansas_-_NCP_1603.jpg')

im = Image.open(BytesIO(img.content))

def send_to_clipboard(clip_type, data): 
    win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
    win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
    win32clipboard.SetClipboardData(clip_type, data) 
    win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()

clip_type = win32clipboard.CF_BITMAP

output = BytesIO()
im.convert("RGB").save(output, "BMP")
data = output.getvalue()[14:]
output.close()

send_to_clipboard(win32clipboard.CF_DIB, data)
```